# how to run DLL Project

Tags: visual-c++

This is the Oculus street view project.....just i am trying to understand and run but i could not do it......please help me

// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.

## include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

## include "stdafx.h"

```
#include "libovrwrapper.h"
#include <OVR.h>

using namespace OVR;

// Ptr<> AddRef'ed, AutoCleaned
bool               bInited = false;
Ptr<DeviceManager> pManager;
Ptr<HMDDevice>     pHMD;
Ptr<SensorDevice>  pSensor;
SensorFusion       pSensorFusion;


LIBOVRWRAPPER_API int OVR_Init()
{
   bInited = false;
   System::Init(Log::ConfigureDefaultLog(LogMask_Regular));

   if (System::IsInitialized())
   {
      int stage = -1;
      while (++stage > -1 && !bInited)
      {
         switch (stage)
         {
            case 0:
               pManager = *DeviceManager::Create();
               if (pManager == NULL)
                  return bInited;
               break;
            case 1:
               pHMD     = *pManager->EnumerateDevices<HMDDevice>().CreateDevice();
               if (pHMD == NULL)
                  return bInited;
               break;
            case 2:
               pSensor = *pHMD->GetSensor();
               if (pSensor == NULL)
                  return bInited;
               break;
            default:
               bInited = true;
               break;
         };
      }
   }

   pSensorFusion.AttachToSensor(pSensor);

   return (bInited?1:0);
}


LIBOVRWRAPPER_API void OVR_Exit()
{
   if (bInited)
   {
      System::Destroy();
   }
}


LIBOVRWRAPPER_API int OVR_QueryHMD(OVR_HMDInfo* refHmdInfo)
{
   if (!bInited)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   HMDInfo src;
   if (pHMD->GetDeviceInfo(&src))
   {
      refHmdInfo->HResolution             = src.HResolution;
        refHmdInfo->VResolution             = src.VResolution;
        refHmdInfo->HScreenSize             = src.HScreenSize;
        refHmdInfo->VScreenSize             = src.VScreenSize;
        refHmdInfo->VScreenCenter           = src.VScreenCenter;
        refHmdInfo->EyeToScreenDistance     = src.EyeToScreenDistance;
        refHmdInfo->LensSeparationDistance  = src.LensSeparationDistance;
        refHmdInfo->InterpupillaryDistance  = src.InterpupillaryDistance;
        refHmdInfo->DistortionK[0]          = src.DistortionK[0];
        refHmdInfo->DistortionK[1]          = src.DistortionK[1];
        refHmdInfo->DistortionK[2]          = src.DistortionK[2];
        refHmdInfo->DistortionK[3]          = src.DistortionK[3];
        refHmdInfo->DesktopX                = src.DesktopX;
        refHmdInfo->DesktopY                = src.DesktopY;
        memcpy(refHmdInfo->DisplayDeviceName, src.DisplayDeviceName, sizeof(refHmdInfo->DisplayDeviceName));       
   }

   return 1;
}
LIBOVRWRAPPER_API int   OVR_PeekYPL(float* yaw, float* pitch, float* roll)
{
      if (!bInited)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   Quatf hmdOrient = pSensorFusion.GetOrientation();
   hmdOrient.GetEulerAngles<Axis_Y, Axis_X, Axis_Z>(yaw, pitch, roll);

   return 1;
}

LIBOVRWRAPPER_API int OVR_Peek(float* w, float* x, float* y,float * z)
{
   if (!bInited)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   Quatf hmdOrient = pSensorFusion.GetOrientation();
   *w = hmdOrient.w;
   *x = hmdOrient.x;
   *y = hmdOrient.y;
   *z = hmdOrient.z;

   //hmdOrient.GetEulerAngles<Axis_Y, Axis_X, Axis_Z>(yaw, pitch, roll);

   return 1;
}

#ifdef LIBOVRWRAPPER_EXPORTS
   #if defined __cplusplus
      #define LIBOVRWRAPPER_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
      #define LIBOVRWRAPPER_API __declspec(dllexport)
   #endif
#else
   #if defined __cplusplus
      #define LIBOVRWRAPPER_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
   #else
      #define LIBOVRWRAPPER_API __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif
#endif

struct OVR_HMDInfo
{   
   unsigned      HResolution;
   unsigned      VResolution;
    float         HScreenSize;
   float         VScreenSize;
    float         VScreenCenter;
    float         EyeToScreenDistance;
    float         LensSeparationDistance;
    float         InterpupillaryDistance;
    float         DistortionK[4];
    int           DesktopX;
   int           DesktopY;
    char          DisplayDeviceName[32];
};


LIBOVRWRAPPER_API int   OVR_Init();
LIBOVRWRAPPER_API void  OVR_Exit();
LIBOVRWRAPPER_API int   OVR_QueryHMD(struct OVR_HMDInfo* refHmdInfo);
LIBOVRWRAPPER_API int   OVR_Peek(float* w, float* x, float* y,float * z);
LIBOVRWRAPPER_API int   OVR_PeekYPL(float* yaw, float* pitch, float* roll);
```

Comment: This is the Oculus SDK project. When this project run successfully, it views a HMD...........but i could't succesfully.
I want to run this type of program which encourage me a lot. Advanced thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to understand, as it doesn't have any real details about what you've tried, what isn't working, etc.

It looks like you are trying to "run" a DLL, which isn't really possible. A DLL has to be loaded by another application. So you would have an executable of some kind that would load this DLL, and call into its OVR_Init and OVR_Exit functions.

Comment: Thank you for cordially reply. This is the Oculus SDK project. When this project run successfully, it will show a HMD...........but i could't succesfully.
I want to run this type of program which encourage me a lot. Advanced thanks.

Comment: How to run Oculus World Demo Programming by using Visual Studio Express 2012 for windows 32 bit